# Should i add indexes to the view or to the main table?

Tags: mysql

I have a view which is consisted by several tables with the same structure.

The performance of the view is working very slow giving the fact that in all of the tables there is a lot of data.

Where should i put my indexes in order to improve my view's performance, in the tables or in the view itself?

Comment: you must show us a little bit more. post the tables structure and the view

Comment: @BerndBuffen The issue is not the indexes themselves, i know how to configure them, i am just asking generally what method is better for the performance. The structure of the view is the same as the tables for that matter

Comment: ok, have you ever tried to create a INDEX on a VIEW Column ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately There is no option to create column as index in view. You have to create indexes on tabels only.

For better performance make all the columns which are used in on class and where class.

Comment: I wasn't aware you can not add indexes in the view, i'm pretty newbie in mysql. Thanks.